# Wicket RepeatingView refresh / rerender ? Possibilities? [List items missing]

Tags: java, wicket

I got a little problem with my wicket application.

The problem is on a page called OverviewPage, here are some panels like the ListPanel, in which my RepeatingView is.

This RepeatingView (List) got some items with a button for each item, if I press the button, I will be redirected to another page (RegistrationPage) and some changes to the RepeatingView (list) are done.

If I now navigate back to the OverviewPage with the RepeatingView (list), the list is exactly the same like before. I did changes to the list items but they are not visible. (I did not press the browser back button, I clicked a link of my navigation)

I know instances of wicket pages last over the session. Can I tell wicket to re-render this page / list again? what possibilities are there? can anyone?

Thanks

EDIT:

The following is the Panel which holds the RepeatingView:

```
/**
 * 
 * Constructor...
 *
 * @param id
 */
public ServiceListPanel(String id) {

    super(id);

    RepeatingView repeating = new RepeatingView("repeating");
    add(repeating);

    int index = 0;

    // add all services to the list

    for (Service service : databaseService.getAllServices()) {

        AbstractItem item = new AbstractItem(repeating.newChildId());

        repeating.add(item);

        item.add(new ActionPanel("actions", new Model<Service>(service)));

        item.add(new Label("name", service.getName()));
        item.add(new Label("description", service.getDescription()));
        item.add(new Label("country", service.getCountry()));

        final int idx = index;
        item.add(AttributeModifier.replace("class", new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {

            private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1L;

            @Override
            public String getObject() {

                return (idx % 2 == 1) ? "even" : "odd";
            }
        }));

        index++;
    }

}
```

The next one is the ActionPanel where the changes should happen:

```
/**
 * 
 * Constructor...
 *
 * @param id
 * @param model
 */
public ActionPanel(String id, final IModel<Service> model) {

    super(id);

    Link<?> link;

    ContextImage image;

    final ServiceUserDetails user = getSession().getUser();

    final Service service = model.getObject();

    // Check for groups and customize the link to subscribe or unsubscribe

    if (checkUserGroups(user, service)) {

        image = new ContextImage("img", "template/img/unsubscribe.gif");

        link = new Link<Void>("select") {

            /**  */
            private static final long   serialVersionUID    = -2153508505463870485L;

            /**
             * 
             * @see org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link#onClick()
             */
            @Override
            public void onClick() {

                ServiceRequest req = new ServiceRequest(service, user, "DELETE");

                serviceProcessor.handleServiceRequest(req);

                setResponsePage(new RegistrationPage());



            }
        };

    } else { // user is not in group

        image = new ContextImage("img", "template/img/subscribe.gif");

        link = new Link<Void>("select") {

            /**  */
            private static final long   serialVersionUID    = -2153508505463870485L;

            /**
             * 
             * @see org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.Link#onClick()
             */
            @Override
            public void onClick() {

                ServiceRequest req = new ServiceRequest(service, user, "PUT");

                serviceProcessor.handleServiceRequest(req);

                setResponsePage(new RegistrationPage());


            }
        };

    }

    link.add(image);

    add(link);

}
```

As you can see the only thing i want to change is one image, a link-image. for subscribing or unsubscribing a service. the list items stay the same.

Iam quite new to wicket and maybe thats my problem.

Hope its better explained now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now.

It was my mistake. The list could be updated BUT not under my conditions:

I used SpringSecurity and Wicket in combination to achieve user authentication. A user autenticated through ldap in my wicketSession. The Autentication holds an user object with all stuff i needed (name, sn, groups, email and more..).

In my RepeatingView, more precisely in my ActionPanel i did some action to modify the LDAP entry of a user by adding him to other groups.

The problem now is: the Authentication which holds the user object, holds the OLD unmodified user object. (Remember: i changed the users groups.)

That is why i didnt see any changes on my ListItems, my condition was like...

```
if (user is in group) {

   addUnSubscribeLink(); 

} else {

   addSubscribeLink(); 

}
```

Thanks for help anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Provide your actionPanel with a `LoadableDetachableModel` instead of a normal `Model`. LDM always fetch new fresh objects, so this might solve your problem. You will probably have to refactor your code quite a bit.

Last time a had a similar issue with a DataTable and it helped.

Comment: More info here on LDMs here -https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/working-with-wicket-models.html#WorkingwithWicketmodels-DetachableModels

Answer (score 2):

You have to differ here. The structure of a Page/Component is constructed once, and than this tree of components is asked to render for each page display (refresh). Some repeaters keep a the list of Components for after the render process, so no matter what you do with the List (changing the elements in it) it will have no effect on the rendered output.

Other repeaters (RefreshingView) do discard all Components after rendering and recreate the components for each render process, hence, if you change the backing list, these changes will be refrected in the rendered output.

Also, no state is keeped outside of sessions. If the session is closed, you can not go back to and old page state.

Without some code, I can not tell you why you see old state after you click your back link.

Answer (score 1):

I generally use ListView for almost all of my repeaters because it is fairly straightforward.  To use a ListView instead I would replace the following lines of your code (note: I skipped some lines that you can leave in-place and broke out `databseService.getAllServices()` so you can verify that it is actually updated at that point):

```
RepeatingView repeating = new RepeatingView("repeating");
for (Service service : databaseService.getAllServices()) {
    AbstractItem item = new AbstractItem(repeating.newChildId());
    repeating.add(item);
    ...
```

With this:

```
List<Service> serviceList = databaseService.getAllServices();
ListView repeating = new ListView("repeating", serviceList) {
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(ListItem item) {
        Service service = (Service) item.getModelObject();
        ...
```

You should then be able to use your item & service variables the same as before.  Also, at this point you can take a look, either with a logger or debugger to verify that your databaseService.getAllServices is returning the correctly updated list.